# Provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52-Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework core and after adding migrations, while updating database I got this error.

Error while updating database:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

Comment: The error is self-explanatory... the server was not found or not accessible You need to follow the instructions it provides.

Comment: Hi @Venkat 123, Please check your connection string if it is correct or not.